# GET request fails on electron but works when I run the URL which failed on the browser

Tags: electron, okta

I'm currently trying to get the authorization token from Okta using a GET request from my app using fetch API. The first step works well and I get the sessionToken. The next step requires  me to pass this sessionToken in the url of a get request . Once this is done I should be getting an html object but what I instead get is a 404 message from the server on the console  and the id_token embedded in the failed url which also is on the console. I have tried every possible fix and yet it doesn't seem to work.

```
    async function getAccessToken(url = '', sessionID= ''){
    const response = await fetch(url + sessionID);
    return response
    
  }
ON THE CONSOLE: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()        the failed url with the id_token
```

When I copy this URL and run it in the browser it works. Response contains the callback url alone and I don't seem to have anyway to access the id_toke. Any way to access this id_ token would do for now.

Comment: Did you try logging the URL to the console immediately before making the request to see if the URL that it is trying to get is actually correct, or if it is getting mixed up somewhere?

Comment: The url is fine not the problem since it works well on the browser

Comment: But did you actually check to see whether the code is requesting the URL you think it is?